# Question showing an older revision, but when editing the latest revision is shown

Tags: bug, edits

When looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22858258/2134785) you can see a big amount of useless text, however when you try to edit the question the text is gone. Screens to show what I mean:

The question:
[image]

On edit:
[image]

So my question is:
Why does it show the text in the question but when editing the text is gone?
Is this a bug?

Comment: The wall of text recognises the shame heaped upon it, and is self-censoring as best it can.

Comment: I can reproduce, also; wierd!

Comment: It's caching! I think. It was added in [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22858258/revisions) 2, but removed in revision 4. Somehow, the question isn't showing the correct revision.

Comment: Mega edit conflict in its worst. (Looks like an edit was approved in the same instant the OP sent edit of his own)

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed] ;)

Comment: @Shadow As far as I can see the wall of text has now been edited in officially

Comment: I guess we'll have a better idea when we can [look it up in the Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/155370/post-history-viewer?PostId=22858258).

Comment: @Richard true, I suspect some super-ubber-rare race condition caused what we saw and doubt it can be reproduced. Normally, edit by OP will auto reject suggested edit, but it was approved in the same second. Guess it can be solved by adding locks or transactions in the code/SQL but as it's one to million chance and solveable by simple edit, not sure it's worth the time. :)

Answer (score 2):

I looked into this as a test-case for a different bug, so figured I'd drop a note on what happened for posterity.

- The asker started an edit to add more information to the question. And while they were editing...
- Someone suggested an edit to add a tag.
- Then the suggested edit was approved via the Improve function which made various corrections to the post body, thus generating a *third* revision.
- The Improved suggested edit was received by the servers roughly 24ms after receiving the asker's edit and roughly 1 minute 24 seconds after the question was originally posted.
- The suggested edit revision and Improved revision were recorded first, thus making the asker's edit ineligible for the grace period, so a separate revision was generated for it instead of rolling it into the initial revision.
- Because the asker's edit was received first, it got a slightly earlier timestamp and became revision #2.
- Because the asker's edit was the last to finish processing, the rendered post contained the body of that edit, with the tags from the suggested edit, and none of the corrections made by the Improve edit.

Comment: There's a difference between "recorded" and "recieved"?

Comment: I'm being a bit sloppy here, @Tiny... But for the purpose of this answer, "received" is when the request started being processed (timestamp fixed, code route established), "recorded" is when the actual `PostHistory` records are live in the database, and "finish processing" is when everything involved in an edit is *done* (post re-rendered & updated with cached body HTML, last editor, last modified date, etc., updates sent, request response sent back to the client).

Comment: In other words, magic happens.